# Why does sorting take so long?

Tags: rust

I am currently trying to learn the syntax of Rust by solving little tasks. I compare the execution time as sanity-checks if I am using the language the right way.

One task is:

1. Create an array of 10000000 random integers in the range 0 - 1000000000
2. Sort it and measure the time
3. Print the time for sorting it

I got the following results:

```
| #   | Language             | Speed  | LOCs |
| --- | -------------------- | ------ | ---- |
| 1   | C++ (with -O3)       | 1.36s  | 1    |
| 2   | Python (with PyPy)   | 3.14s  | 1    |
| 3   | Ruby                 | 5.04s  | 1    |
| 4   | Go                   | 6.17s  | 1    |
| 5   | C++                  | 7.95s  | 1    |
| 6   | Python (with Cython) | 11.51s | 1    |
| 7   | PHP                  | 36.28s | 1    |
```

Now I wrote the following Rust code:

**rust.rs**

```
extern crate rand;
extern crate time;

use rand::Rng;
use time::PreciseTime;

fn main() {
    let n = 10000000;
    let mut array = Vec::new();

    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    for _ in 0..n {
        //array[i] = rng.gen::<i32>();
        array.push(rng.gen::<i32>());
    }

    // Sort
    let start = PreciseTime::now();
    array.sort();
    let end = PreciseTime::now();

    println!("{} seconds for sorting {} integers.", start.to(end), n);
}
```

with the following **Cargo.toml**:

```
[package]
name = "hello_world" # the name of the package
version = "0.0.1"    # the current version, obeying semver
authors = [ "you@example.com" ]
[[bin]]
name = "rust"
path = "rust.rs"
[dependencies]
rand = "*" # Or a specific version
time = "*"
```

I compiled it with `cargo run rust.rs` and ran the binary. It outputs

```
PT18.207168155S seconds for sorting 10000000 integers.
```

Note that this is much slower than Python. I guess I am doing something wrong. (The complete code of rust and of the other languages is [here](https://github.com/MartinThoma/rosetta-code/tree/master/sorting/integer-array) if you are interested.)

Why does it take so long to sort with Rust? How can I make it faster?

Comment: If you see other problems with my code, please let me know it in the comments. I am currently learning rust. Or if you know how to format the time to `18.21s for sorting 10000000 integers`.

Comment: Rust is using merge sort. Python is using TimSort which is a highly optimized version of merge sort. Rusts version might just not be as efficient.

Comment: @mpkorstanje As far as I know TimSort is merge sort + insertion sort if not many elements have to be sorted. I think this should not have such a significant impact in a single (but large) sorting action.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about benchmarking unoptimized code.

Comment: @райтфолд That does not make it off-topic.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit we disagree once again.

Comment: @райтфолд Then you are incorrect. I refer you to the Stack Overflow Help Centre, where reasons that something is off-topic are enumerated. Technical design failing in a benchmark attempt is not one of them.

Comment: @moose You can generate the array in one line with an iterator: `let mut array: Vec<i32> = rand::thread_rng().gen_iter().take(n).collect();`

Comment: @moose Additionally, you should use `rand::weak_rng()` instead of `rand::thread_rng()` to be more competitive with your other benchmarks.

Comment: @AustinB The random number generation does not play a role. For this "benchmark" I am only interested in sorting. The random numbers were only created to have something to sort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I Tried your code on my computer, running it with `cargo run` gives:

```
PT11.634640178S seconds for sorting 10000000 integers.
```

And with `cargo run --release` (turning on optimizations) gives:

```
PT1.004434739S seconds for sorting 10000000 integers.
```

Comment: Wow. Do you have any idea why optimizations make such a big difference? Do you know which kind of opimization makes this difference?

Comment: I must admit I do not know precisely, but my guess would be to look at inlining function calls. Mainly the inlining of the comparison operator.

Comment: @moose "why optimizations make such a big difference" - that's kind of the point of optimizations. ^_^ If they didn't make a big difference, they wouldn't be worth it! If you are truly curious, you can compile the code to the LLVM IR and inspect the differences between optimized and unoptimized.

Comment: @Shepmaster It is desirable that optimizations improve things. This does not explain why it succeeds and how it does so.

Comment: @moose it wasn't really intended to explain, that's why it's just a comment. :-) It sounds like you have another good top-level question to ask!

Comment: @moose Perhaps you should take a look at [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler#Common_themes). Rust lets its LLVM backend handle most of the optimization work, and LLVM may not necessarily perform all the optimizations listed there, but it'd be a good place to start if you want to understand why optimization has such a great effect.

Comment: @moose Additionally, the `--release` flag enables other performance improvements that are done in the compiler itself and applied to dependencies as well, like omitting debugging information and source code references from the final assembly, which can otherwise add significant bloat.